# Connecting to database using non-standard port from Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

In a Visual Studio 2019 project, I open Server Explorer and try to connect to a MySQL Server 127.0.0.1 at a port other than 3306. When I try to include :port it balks immediately and won't try to connect. How do you specify the port? Thanks.